# No 3d support with dual video cards

Tags: 12.04, graphics, 3d

I have a standard **Intel Graphics** card and one **ATI Radeon HD 6490M**.

1. There is no support of 3d effects with my dual video cards?
2. What could be the problem?

My computer is a **HP Probook 4530s** with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Proprietary Drivers for AMD.

Search for "Jockey" in the Dash, then click Additional Drivers.  Find the one that says "AMD" in the title.

Click Activate.  It should work.